# vertically align the text in an asp:LinkButton

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following ASP.NET code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.MainPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        :root {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        #div-root {
            position:relative;
            text-align:center; 
            height:100%; 
        }
        #div {
            position:relative;
            height:10%;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        #div1 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
        #div2 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
        #div3 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="MainPage" runat="server" style="height:330px; text-align:center">
        <div id="div-root">
            <div id="div">
                <h1 style="height:100%">Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="div1">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" BackColor="Green" Width="20%" Height="100%" Text="Locate nearest instalment" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="White"/>
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" BackColor="blue" Width="20%" Height="100%" Text="Payments" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="White"/>
            </div>
            <div id="div3">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" BackColor="red" Width="20%" Height="100%" Text="Record Grievances" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="White"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

In this code, I want to have all the text in the middle (vertically) of the div element. However, I am not able to do so. I tried stuff like `vertical-align:middle` but to no avail. How do I go about this?

---

The rendered output:

[image: rendered-output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0032)https://localhost:44305/MainPage -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style data-merge-styles="true"></style><title>

</title>
    <style>
        :root {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        #div-root {
            position:relative;
            text-align:center; 
            height:100%; 
        }
        #div {
            position:relative;
            height:10%;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        #div1 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
        #div2 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
        #div3 {
            position:relative;
            height:30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="https://localhost:44305/MainPage" id="MainPage" style="height:330px; text-align:center">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="oGqW+RYbX0ld1g+np3IIa4+TKK6xYzvIutKaF6KrVVi4g6rE/zquQrU38bIjCkUtDCvDchtXiXb1io8FrEZVBDLFm0+JCg4gm6BFDMPWA0A=">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['MainPage'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.MainPage;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="0C7D29E3">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="4jERSQFovFlNWeB6S2OimCFDsf52/Ge9ZnV2TgpjYAaF4+3frJiqU1RVTeW+HCtRCZBTed2yjjfs6nvccUl8Gd46PDdnogM37tKUPj0ktVcVZ9+PMXxmbNcdzIIDwweKFcyAoAEER4fnLrq8xCeRxQ4J9Xzp7sFhQX1kbHyNorY=">
</div>
        <div id="div-root">
            <div id="div">
                <h1 style="height:100%">Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="div1">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl02&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;color:White;background-color:Green;text-decoration:none;height:100%;width:20%;">Locate nearest instalment</a>
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl03&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;color:White;background-color:Blue;text-decoration:none;height:100%;width:20%;">Payments</a>
            </div>
            <div id="div3">
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl04&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;color:White;background-color:Red;text-decoration:none;height:100%;width:20%;">Record Grievances</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


</body><editor-card style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: auto;"><div dir="ltr" style="all: initial;"><div style="animation: initial; transition: initial; color: initial; color-scheme: initial; font: initial; font-feature-settings: initial; font-kerning: initial; font-optical-sizing: initial; font-variation-settings: initial; forced-color-adjust: initial; text-orientation: initial; text-rendering: initial; -webkit-font-smoothing: initial; -webkit-locale: initial; -webkit-text-orientation: initial; -webkit-writing-mode: initial; writing-mode: initial; zoom: initial; place-content: initial; place-items: initial; place-self: initial; alignment-baseline: initial; appearance: initial; backdrop-filter: initial; backface-visibility: initial; background: initial; background-blend-mode: initial; baseline-shift: initial; block-size: initial; border-block-end: initial; border-block-start: initial; border: initial; border-radius: initial; border-collapse: initial; border-inline-end: initial; border-inline-start: initial; bottom: initial; box-shadow: initial; box-sizing: initial; break-after: initial; break-before: initial; break-inside: initial; buffered-rendering: initial; caption-side: initial; caret-color: initial; clear: initial; clip: initial; clip-path: initial; clip-rule: initial; color-interpolation: initial; color-interpolation-filters: initial; color-rendering: initial; columns: initial; column-fill: initial; gap: initial; column-rule: initial; column-span: initial; contain: initial; contain-intrinsic-size: initial; content: initial; counter-increment: initial; counter-reset: initial; cursor: initial; cx: initial; cy: initial; d: initial; display: initial; dominant-baseline: initial; empty-cells: initial; fill: initial; fill-opacity: initial; fill-rule: initial; filter: initial; flex: initial; flex-flow: initial; float: initial; flood-color: initial; flood-opacity: initial; grid: initial; grid-area: initial; height: initial; hyphens: initial; image-orientation: initial; image-rendering: initial; inline-size: initial; isolation: initial; left: initial; letter-spacing: initial; lighting-color: initial; line-break: initial; list-style: initial; margin-block-end: initial; margin-block-start: initial; margin: initial; margin-inline-end: initial; margin-inline-start: initial; marker: initial; mask: initial; mask-type: initial; max-block-size: initial; max-height: initial; max-inline-size: initial; max-width: initial; min-block-size: initial; min-height: initial; min-inline-size: initial; min-width: initial; mix-blend-mode: initial; object-fit: initial; object-position: initial; offset: initial; opacity: initial; order: initial; origin-trial-test-property: initial; orphans: initial; outline: initial; outline-offset: initial; overflow-anchor: initial; overflow-wrap: initial; overflow: initial; overscroll-behavior-block: initial; overscroll-behavior-inline: initial; overscroll-behavior: initial; padding-block-end: initial; padding-block-start: initial; padding: initial; padding-inline-end: initial; padding-inline-start: initial; paint-order: initial; perspective: initial; perspective-origin: initial; pointer-events: initial; position: absolute; quotes: initial; r: initial; resize: initial; right: initial; ruby-position: initial; rx: initial; ry: initial; scroll-behavior: initial; scroll-margin-block: initial; scroll-margin: initial; scroll-margin-inline: initial; scroll-padding-block: initial; scroll-padding: initial; scroll-padding-inline: initial; scroll-snap-align: initial; scroll-snap-stop: initial; scroll-snap-type: initial; shape-image-threshold: initial; shape-margin: initial; shape-outside: initial; shape-rendering: initial; size: initial; speak: initial; stop-color: initial; stop-opacity: initial; stroke: initial; stroke-dasharray: initial; stroke-dashoffset: initial; stroke-linecap: initial; stroke-linejoin: initial; stroke-miterlimit: initial; stroke-opacity: initial; stroke-width: initial; tab-size: initial; table-layout: initial; text-align: initial; text-align-last: initial; text-anchor: initial; text-combine-upright: initial; text-decoration: initial; text-decoration-skip-ink: initial; text-indent: initial; text-overflow: initial; text-shadow: initial; text-size-adjust: initial; text-transform: initial; text-underline-position: initial; top: initial; touch-action: initial; transform: initial; transform-box: initial; transform-origin: initial; transform-style: initial; user-select: initial; vector-effect: initial; vertical-align: initial; visibility: initial; -webkit-app-region: initial; border-spacing: initial; -webkit-border-image: initial; -webkit-box-align: initial; -webkit-box-decoration-break: initial; -webkit-box-direction: initial; -webkit-box-flex: initial; -webkit-box-ordinal-group: initial; -webkit-box-orient: initial; -webkit-box-pack: initial; -webkit-box-reflect: initial; -webkit-font-size-delta: initial; -webkit-highlight: initial; -webkit-hyphenate-character: initial; -webkit-line-break: initial; -webkit-line-clamp: initial; -webkit-mask-box-image: initial; -webkit-mask: initial; -webkit-mask-composite: initial; -webkit-perspective-origin-x: initial; -webkit-perspective-origin-y: initial; -webkit-print-color-adjust: initial; -webkit-rtl-ordering: initial; -webkit-ruby-position: initial; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: initial; -webkit-text-combine: initial; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: initial; -webkit-text-emphasis: initial; -webkit-text-emphasis-position: initial; -webkit-text-fill-color: initial; -webkit-text-security: initial; -webkit-text-stroke: initial; -webkit-transform-origin-x: initial; -webkit-transform-origin-y: initial; -webkit-transform-origin-z: initial; -webkit-user-drag: initial; -webkit-user-modify: initial; white-space: initial; widows: initial; width: initial; will-change: initial; word-break: initial; word-spacing: initial; x: initial; y: initial; z-index: 2147483647;"><link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://hokifickgkhplphjiodbggjmoafhignh/fonts/fabric-icons.css"><div style="all: initial;"></div></div></div></editor-card></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is CSS that works for your markup. The centering is achieved through `display: flex;`.

Try to lose all the inline CSS that you're currently generating by manually fiddling with properties in Visual Studio.

```css
html, body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div-root {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.myButton {
  height: 30%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.myButton a {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: green;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-root">
  <div id="div1" class="myButton">
    <a href="##">Locate nearest instalment</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="myButton">
    <a href="##">Payments</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="myButton">
    <a href="##">Record Grievances</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Huh? You can use `<asp:LinkButton>` if you want to. That's server-side code, the browser does not care what you do on the server side. The browser gets to see the HTML structure seen in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You an always use a flex

```
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
```

in your CSS, to the element you want things to be centered horizontally and vertically, and i highly recommend that you read about flexbox its a must nowadays,
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
take a look at this guide

Comment: Yea probably, i wonder why dont you even use class for the divs, styling using ID's in your scenario is not efficient, if you still want to use the ID's for some reason, just drop the CSS in #div1,2,3.